Capture bit-fields by reference in a lambda expression
According to cppreference, bit-fields can only be captured by copy: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda. Period.
At the same time, one can see certain scenarios, e.g.:
struct U {
    int i : 4;
};

constexpr int foo() {
    const auto & [y] = U{5};
    return [&y = y]() { return y; }();
}

static_assert( foo() == 5 );

where both GCC and Clang permit capture of bit-fields by reference even during evaluation of constant expressions. Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bcbqcGKd7
Are there any exceptions not mentioned in cppreference or proposals to future C++ standards, which legalize capture of bit-fields by reference?
Update:
If one replaces the capture in lambda expression with [&y]:
return [&y]() { return y; }();

then compilers diverge:

GCC behaves exactly the same as above accepting the program.
MSVC starts rejecting it with the error:


error C3693: 'y': bit-fields cannot be captured by reference


and Clang is somewhere in the middle rejecting only constant evaluation of foo() with unrelated error.
Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rTj659ooY


But you're not capturing a bit-field, you capture a const int.

Yet I'm curious: the code is handled quite differently according to compilers. I'm wondering why.

In order to precise Some programmer dude answer: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field#:~:text=Pointers%20and%20non%2Dconst%20references,is%20bound%20to%20that%20temporary.

MSVC issue fixed: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/A-capture-in-lambda-expression-of-consta/10681486

See also: CWG1695
The type of the member of the closure type used to capture y is const int& (because the type of x is const int)
When you try to bind a const int& to a bit-field, it binds to a temporary.
The lifetime of this temporary is extended to the lifetime of the lambda (in the same way struct X { const int& r; }; X x{ .r = 3 }; would extend the lifetime of the temporary materialized from 3).
So you don't capture the bit-field by reference. If it weren't a const reference:
struct U {
    int i : 4;
};

constexpr int foo() {
    auto [y] = U{5};
    return [&y = y]() { return y; }();
}

static_assert( foo() == 5 );

... it wouldn't compile.
If you made it const again by making the bit-field const int i : 4;, it compiles again.

Thanks. And if one modifies in the original program the capture section to [&y], does it change the meaning of the program? Because now both Clang and MSVC reject it. In particular, MSVC complains error C3693: 'y': bit-fields cannot be captured by reference. Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rTj659ooY

@Fedor Yeah, you explicitly can't capture bit-fields by reference: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#12.sentence-4 (Both GCC and Clang do not implement this, but Clang rejects this for an unrelated reason: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/95225 )

And [&y = y] is an entirely different beast from [&y]. For one, &y=y is implemented with a member of reference type, but &y can't be: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#12 (so there is no reference to extend lifetime)
